# Json Object Sorting in Php

Tags: php, json, wordpress, object

I m not professional and i have a problem.
I call assists created with json object in database.
This code is calling in the order of creation, but I want to sort the number from the large to the smallest. I tried many things but couldn't.
I need your helps. Thanks

```
// add action to check for table item
add_action('gdlr_print_item_selector', 'gdlr_league_table', 10, 2);
function gdlr_league_table($type, $settings = array()){
    if($type == 'gol-krali'){
        gdlr_print_league($settings);
    }
}

//table item
function gdlr_print_league($settings){
    // query league table
    $args['post_type'] = 'player';
    $args['posts_per_page'] = (empty($settings['num-fetch']))? '555': $settings['num-fetch'];

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // getting table array
    while($query->have_posts()){ $query->the_post();
        $player_val = gdlr_lms_decode_preventslashes(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'gdlr-soccer-player-settings', true));
        $assists = empty($player_val)? array(): json_decode($player_val, true); 
        $table[get_the_title()]['p'] = ($assists);  
    }
    echo '<div class="gdlr-item gdlr-league-table-item" ' . $item_id . $margin_style . ' >';
    if(empty($settings['style']) || $settings['style'] == 'full'){
        gdlr_print_league_table($table);
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

// table
function gdlr_print_league_table($player){
    echo '<table class="gdlr-league-table" >';
?>
<tr class="gdlr-table-second-head gdlr-title-font">
    <th class="gdlr-table-pos"><?php echo __('Sıra', 'gdlr-soccer'); ?></th>
    <th class="gdlr-table-team"><?php echo __('Oyuncu', 'gdlr-soccer'); ?></th>
    <th class="gdlr-table-p">Asist</th>
</tr>
<?php
    $count = 1;
    foreach($player as $player_name => $score ){
?>
<tr>
    <td class="gdlr-table-pos"><?php echo $count; ?></td>
    <td class="gdlr-table-team"><?php echo $player_name ?></td>
    <td class="gdlr-table-p"><?php echo $score['p']['player-stats']['assists']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
        $count++;
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the `$payer` array with `uasort` just before your loop:

```
uasort($player, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['p']['player-stats']['assists']-$a['p']['player-stats']['assists'];
});
foreach($player as $player_name => $score ){
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Normally the sorting is as follows;https://ibb.co/hVh2nPH , when I use this code; https://ibb.co/vs4wH0m .

Comment: I want to sort number higher to lower.

Comment: Ah I see, `$score` is not a number, but a nested array. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ah it s worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi again. I have a new question. Some of these players don't have these numbers, but they call them. I don't want to show them. Can I just show the numbers?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? If you want to exclude something, then add within the `foreach` loop a condition: `if (some condition) continue;`

Comment: For example; https://ibb.co/XpnJZ9b , If there is no number of assists, ı don't want this player show on the this table

Comment: That sounds like a different question. It is not related to the question about sorting.

Comment: yes it s different question.

Comment: If you cannot make it work with an `if ... continue;` construct, could I ask you to post it as a new question? But if you do, be sure to simplify the code so it just focuses on that problem alone.

Comment: I guess I can't create a new question. It says I have to wait a few days.

Comment: Your account probably does not have a good track record on asking questions. This one was downvoted and closed because unclear. So take this time to edit this question and apply the advice given in [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One thing that makes the current question look bad is that the code is doing a lot more than what is relevant for the question. The query is irrelevant; and the calls to `gdlr_` functions only complicate things. Even the HTML output is not that relevant. Minimise and clarify. Then it might be reopened, giving you credit.